# Action attribute of <p:commandButton> is not called

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, xhtml, facelets

I am trying to call the `addMoreStatus` method by using the `action` attribute of the `<p:commandButton>`, but it is not called. I have also used ajax to see if the value of session variable changes or not. Unfortunately the session variable which is inside the get more status never gets updated. toIndex always shows 5.

1)xhtml

```
<h:body>
    <c:if test="#{statusBean.init == null}"/>
    <h:form id="foo">
        <p:commandButton id="bar" action="#{statusBean.addMoreStatus}"
             value="test" update="test"></p:commandButton> 

        <h:outputLabel value="#{sessionScope['toIndex']}" id="test" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

2) statusBean

```
public String getInit(){

        System.out.println("inside getInit");

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
        int toIndex = 5;
        session.setAttribute("toIndex", toIndex);

        return null;        
    }

    public void addMoreStatus(){

        System.out.println("inside addMoreStatus");
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
        int toIndex = (int) session.getAttribute("toIndex");
        toIndex = toIndex + 5;
        session.setAttribute("toIndex", toIndex);
    }
```

Comment: What is bean scope in your bean ?

Comment: What's the meaning of the `<c:if>` tag there? Remove it and please create a getter which has no business logic. I'm not 100% sure but maybe if you move your `<h:outputLabel>` outside the `<h:form>` the example may work as expected.

Comment: Is your getInit() method is getting called before addMoreStatus()